# Having trouble understanding this const pointer error

Tags: c, pointers, constants

My program needs to determine whether or not a pointer s1 has any characters from s2 in it and then return a pointer to that position in s1, otherwise return NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * strpbrk(const char *, const char *);

int main(void){
const char *s1 = "hello";
const char *s2 = "world";

printf("Repeated character in s1 is %p", *strpbrk(s1, s2));

}

char * strpbrk(const char * s1, const char * s2){
char *p1, *p2;

p1 = s1;
p2 = s2;
for(; *p1 != '\0'; p1++){
    for(; *p2 != '\0'; p2++){
        if(*p1 == *p2){
            break;
        }
        else{
            return '\0';
        }
    }
}
return p1;
}
```

Keep getting this error:

```
test.c: In function ‘strpbrk’:
test.c:16:5: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  p1 = s1;
     ^
test.c:17:5: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  p2 = s2;
```

Comment: It's important to know that this isn't an error, it's a warning - the two of which are quite different. And the reason for the warning is because you declared `p1` and `p2` as a `char` as opposed to a `const char`.

Comment: I see warnings, not errors.

Comment: I's think the message is obvious. You have a const pointee on one side, and a non-const one on the other. You discard the qualifer.

Comment: sorry that's what I meant to say, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I tried adding const to the decleration of p1 and p2, but then it would give me a warning saying that the const was discarded in the return statement return p1;

Comment: declare pointers are constant are you're good, since you're not changing the pointed data in your routine (also change return type by `const char *`)

Comment: I'd like to add: glad you're considering that warning as an error, because that could have had serious consequences. Don't leave warnings in your code.

Comment: And although it's a warning, not an error, **you should heed it**.  Your `s1` and `s2` point at string literals, and modifying the contents of a string literal produces undefined behavior.  Your program attempts to modify the string pointed to by `p1`, which it must not do if `p1` in fact points to a string literal, or indeed to an array `const char`, as `s1` and `s2` could do.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed Do you get why assigning a `const char *` to a `char *` is a problem?

Comment: @John Bollinger. Thanks. Though I'm still new to C and am not sure what you mean by "Your program attempts to modify the strings pointed to by p1". I'm simply scanning through the array, and not modifying anything. Coudl you please clarify that for me? Thanks.

Comment: @immibis. I'm fairly new to C. I'm not sure why that is a problem. To be honest, I've been having trouble understanding the whole concept of const pointers. Could you please explain why assigning a const char* to a char* is a problem?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed Well a `const char *` is a pointer to a char that you're not allowed to change. But if you had a `const char *a`, if you could just write `char *b = a; *b = 'X';` that would defeat the purpose because now you're changing it.

Comment: The OP is using the strpbrk function declaration as specified by the standard and wonders why he can't implement it without warnings in standard C. The reason why is actually because of a "bug" in the C standard. So this is a pretty good question.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed, I retract my assertion that your code attempts to modify the string pointed-to by `p1`.  Nevertheless, you should heed your compiler's warnings until and unless you understand well where and when you can safely ignore them.  Since in this case you *don't* modify the strings, you can and should declare `p1`, `p2`, *and* `strpbrk()` itself as `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inconsistency in several of the standard library functions, `strpbrk`, `strstr` etc. The standard demands that they return a non-constant pointer to the found item inside a const-qualified string. What the standard committee was smoking when they decided to add const-correctness to the parameters of these library functions, but not to the return types, I have no idea.

There is no way that you can reliably implement such a function in standard C, since you are not allowed to convert from a "qualified pointer to type" to a "pointer of type". C11 6.7.6.1:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically
>   qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

This is why you keep getting compiler warnings. Violating this rule is listed as undefined behavior by the (non-normative) Annex J:

> Two pointer types that are required to be compatible are not identically qualified, or are not pointers to compatible types (6.7.6.1).

So the answer to your question is that functions like `strpbrk` and `strstr` cannot get implemented safely and portably in standard C. They will have to be implemented by using either non-standard language extensions or another programming language.

The sound solution is to ignore the function declaration as specified by the standard and use a rational one instead. Either

```
char* strpbrk_rw (char* s1, const char* s2); // read/write parameter
```

or

```
const char* strpbrk_ro (const char* s1, const char* s2); // read-only parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get rid of the compiler warning is to change `p1` and  `p2` to pointers to const char and then add a cast when you return `p1`. That way readers of the code will see that you don't intend to modify the string arguments.

There also were a couple of bugs in the implementation that I (hopefully) ironed out.

```
char * strpbrk(const char * s1, const char * s2) {
    const char *p1, *p2;

    for (p1 = s1; *p1 != '\0'; p1++) { // out is a label
        for (p2 = s2; *p2 != '\0'; p2++) {
            if (*p1 == *p2) {
                // Match found
                return (char*)p1;
            }
        }
    }
    // No match found
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I believe that the cast invokes poorly-specified behavior as per 6.7.6.1. The pointer types are not compatible. You shouldn't cast away qualifiers.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed, implementing `strpbrk` in pure C is problematic. In C++ there are two overloaded versions, one with `const` parameters and return type, one without. In C there is just this version that specifies const parameters and non-const return type. `strpbrk` is part of the C library, so you don't have to implement it yourself other than as an exercise.